# How to choose version of .NET Core with creating a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have both 1.0 and 1.1 installed, but whenever I try to create a new ASP.NET MVC application it defaults to 1.0.  There is a dropdown that allows you to target different versions of the .NET framework but nothing for .NET CORE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that at this moment. We need a new `VS 2015 Tooling` for that.
Right now the latest version is [.NET Core 1.0.1 – VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/release-notes.md). With this version you can create a project using packages in the `1.0.1` version.

I guess they will delivery a new version of VS 2015 Tooling when the `.Net Core 1.1.0` becomes `LTS`.

Right now, you have to create a new project and change the packages version manually.

Comment: Thanks Fab ... that makes sense.

Comment: 1.1 was released yesterday btw ;)